# How to resize the camera display in A-Frame?

Tags: html, augmented-reality, aframe

I am trying to create a scene using A-Frame then add a camera to display the camera on the a-scene. However, I cannot find a way to control the camera size. Below is the sample code I am using:

```
     <a-scene 
            vr-mode-ui='enabled: false' embedded arjs='sourceType: webcam; sourceWidth:1280;   sourceHeight:960; displayWidth: 1280;  displayHeight: 960; debugUIEnabled: false;'>

           <!--aframe camera-->
            <a-camera gps-camera rotation-reader></a-camera>
     </a-scene>
```

Do I need to add anything else in the properties?

Comment: Change the source height and width but not the display height and width. Hope that helps.

Comment: Unclear what `camera size` means in this context. Maybe you want to position the camera? Look into camera rig: https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/components/camera.html#examples

Comment: do you mean the scene size on your page? If so look into **embedded** parameter to **<**a-scene**>**